# Kelvin resistance measurement accuracy?

Tags: resistors

In a data acquisition system voltage is sampled. For some reason we need the current values instead of voltage. One can do it by just dividing voltage to a resistance R. The point is the resistance is not precisely 250 ohm so we need to measure it more accurately. We have a constant current supply which is precise for 2 current levels 4mA and 20mA. We applied first constant 4mAmp and then 20mAmp to the resistance and measured the voltage with a voltmeter. 
Then we calculated the resistance of that resistor for each measurement.
The point is at different currents the resistance is measured different. 
Data acquisition will measure the current loop's voltage correspondences coming from the device spitting exactly between 4 to 20mAmps. My question is which resistance value is more precise since the resistance changing with the current. Do you think the best way is to take the average of 2 measurements at 4 and 20 mAamps? Another thing is how can we trust the voltmeter's readings. Is there such thing as digital voltmeter calibration? Does it make sense for our resistance measurement?

Comment: 4/20mA is usually just used for current-mode data interfaces. Why would you use this to do a precision resistance measurement?

Comment: How much variation of R are we talking about? Could it be originated by load effects influenting the measure (e.g. output impedance of the current source not being the same for 4 mA and 20 mA ) ?

Comment: "For some reason we need the current values instead of voltage" - do you actually know what you want or is it likely that anyone answering will be wasting their time? Prove to me YOU are capable of understanding your own requirements then someone might believe YOU are capable of understanding answers to this question.

Comment: we need a calibration line which has current in x axis. are u satisfied? or u need more ..?

Comment: It would help if you could describe the device that is in series with the 4/20mA current loop - the one that you are trying to infer the current of - it's likely it is not (or should not) be regarded as a simple resistor. "x axis" - what does this mean?

Comment: http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/823